# Gulp streams not supported Error using gulp-istanbul

Tags: node.js, gulp, istanbul

I'm getting an error with streams.

I'm working on adding istanbul to my existing mocha task.  When I run this task I get the error below.

I'm using [gulp-istanbul](https://github.com/SBoudrias/gulp-istanbul)

(note: the `config.test.src.bdd.features` is set to the value `'test/bdd/features/**/*-spec.js'`)

```
var stream = gulp.src([config.test.src.bdd.features], { read: false });

gulp.task('mocha-bdd-features', function(cb) {
    process.env.PORT = 8001;
    return stream
        .pipe(istanbul())
        .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire())
        .pipe(mocha({
            compilers: {
                js: babel
            },
            reporter: config.test.mocha.reporter,
            ui: 'bdd'
        }))
        .on('finish', function () {
            stream.pipe(istanbul.writeReports())
            stream.pipe(istanbul.enforceThresholds({thresholds: {global: 90}}))
            stream.on('end', cb);
        });
});
```

the error I get is:

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: streams not supported
```

and who knows I may not be setting up this task right when trying to incorporate gulp-istanbul but trying to at least get past this error first.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue. 
I believe the problem is in line:

```
var stream = gulp.src([config.test.src.bdd.features], { read: false });
```

Setting the *read* option to *false* causes the file.contents to be null and therefore istanbul is not able to cover the files. (check [here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsread))

so try the same thing but without the *read* option.

```
var stream = gulp.src([config.test.src.bdd.features]);
```

Hope this helps.